# Calling a PHP class method and getting the return value using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm creating a little project for myself. I'm not a very experienced programmer, so I began creating the project in PHP. Soon it became evident that running PHP functions and class methods via HTML button clicks wasn't the most straightforward of tasks.

I have some test code set up. First I created an HTML form, from which I want to read user-input values:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="POST">
    Title: <br> <input type="text" id="title"> <br>
    Description: <br> <input type="text" id="description"> <br>
    Priority: <br> <input type="number" id="priority"> <br> <br>
    <input type="button" id="ajaxTest" value="Send>
</form>
```

Now, when the button with id #ajaxTest is clicked, I want to call one of the class methods in a PHP-file that I've created. To this end, I googled around and ended up with the following jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ajaxTest").click( function() {

        $t = $("#title").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.example.com/task.php",
            data: "t="+t
        }).done(function(results) {
            $("#results").html(results).hide().fadeIn();
        })
    });

</script>
```

There is also a div-element with id #results in the HTML, to show the resultant data.

Now, the task.php being called looks like as follows (simplified for readibility):

```
<?php
class Task {
    private $title;
    private $description;

    function SetTitle($t) {
        $this->title = $t;
    }

    function GetTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function SetDescription($d) {
        $this->description = $d;
    }

    function GetDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

How would I go about calling the different member functions of this class via jQuery/AJAX and getting their return values for input to DOM? I take I'll have to create an intermediary class like TaskHandler that initiates the object and so on, but I'm at a complete loss. Been at it almost the whole day, but I've failed to find an answer that would've lead me to a working solution. Ever so thankful for your help!

edit: I have now edited the jQuery and it looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#ajaxTest").click( function() {

        var t = $("#title").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.example.com/taskHandler.php",
            data: {"t": t},
            success: function(response) {
                 $("#results").html(response);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

and taskHandler.php is below

```
<?php
    require_once("task.php");

    $t = new Task();
    $t->SetTitle($_POST['t']);

    $output = $t->GetTitle();
    echo $output;
```

Still don't get anything to show up, though. What's it I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Normally you would have one PHP file per "action" as each request address is supposed to perform one operation *only*. Then you just change the request URL based on the function you wish to call.

Comment: How would these PHP files be formed? I guess that's pretty much the core of my question :)

Comment: `SetTitle.php`, `GetTitle.php`, `SetDescription.php`... You get the idea :)

Comment: Haha, yeah :) But what's the content and how do I get them to return stuff back? :)

Comment: Send content via URL query string parameters or posted data, and process the returned data (most simply as strings for this example)... You need to know how to return data from PHP if you are going to use PHP :)

Comment: First of all, use [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method to prevent the form from being submitted when the submit button is clicked. Second, `$t = $("#title").val();` is wrong, it should be `var t = $("#title").val();`. Third, pass your parameters like this, `data: {t: t},`. Finally, you're only passing title to *task.php* page, what do you want to do with it? What is the expected output?

Comment: Also *never* use button `click` events to control form submission. A keyboard submission will bypass your code. Always use the `submit` event :)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I guess that's what my question was aiming at. How do I handle the AJAX query in PHP and send something back. Also, seems I confused PHP and JavaScript syntax with that var t thingie :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for the tip :) Just getting started here. Learning by doing (a lot of mistakes and bad code) :D

Comment: Edited the original question with what I've gathered from your replies and the Internet so far :)

Comment: Give this a try: `data: {"t": t},`  instead of `data: {t: t},`

Comment: @AxelAmthor Thanks! There was definitely an error there, however, this didn't get it working :/

Comment: can you see in firebug or dev tools, whats actually sent to the server?

Answer (score 2):

As of the long comment list on this question just one thing which is probably messing up the AJAX call:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="POST">
    Title: <br> <input type="text" id="title"> <br>
    Description: <br> <input type="text" id="description"> <br>
    Priority: <br> <input type="number" id="priority"> <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" id="ajaxTest" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The submit button usually submits the entire form. As an empty action parameter is provided, the post action goes to the current page. This will immediately reload, and interrupt a probably issued but not completely sent AJAX request.

Change:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="POST">
    Title: <br> <input type="text" id="title"> <br>
    Description: <br> <input type="text" id="description"> <br>
    Priority: <br> <input type="number" id="priority"> <br> <br>
    <input type="button" id="ajaxTest" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Still getting nothing though :/ Edited the suggested correction in to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The final problem lied in the AJAX request, which the web browser regarded as cross-domain because of the format. Actually it was working in the same domain.

```
url: "http://www.example.com/taskHandler.php",
```

As soon as I changed to just

```
url: "taskHandler.php"
```

it started working.

Thanks everyone for your input! I learned a lot here trying to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the following steps:
if you expecting to call only one backend method per request, then consider allowing only one of those fields for input: `'title'` or `'description'`.
*** *js part:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ajaxTest").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefaut();
        var title, desc, type;
        if (title = $("#title").val().trim()){
            type = 'title';
        } else if (desc = $("#description").val().trim()){
            type = 'description';
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.example.com/task.php",
            data: {'action': type, 'value': title || desc} // 'value' is for setting certain property, to return an existing property send only 'action' param
        }).done(function(results) {
            $("#results").html(results).hide().fadeIn();
        })
    });
</script>
```

php part:
***task.php***

```
<?php
class Task {
    private $title;
    private $description;

    function SetTitle($t) {
        $this->title = $t;
    }

    function GetTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function SetDescription($d) {
        $this->description = $d;
    }

    function GetDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $value = (isset($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['value']))? $_POST['value'] : null;
    $task = new Task();
    $method = (($value)? 'Set' : 'Get') . ucfirst($action);
    if method_exists($task, $method){  // BTW - method name should start with a lowercase letter
        $result = ($value)? $task->$method($value) : $task->$method();
        echo ($result)? $result : "";
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate the getTitle method:

```
class Task {
    private $title;
    private $description;

    function SetTitle($t) {
        $this->title = $t;
    }

    function GetTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function SetDescription($d) {
        $this->description = $d;
    }

    function GetTitle() {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

I recomend you to test the php file as separated file, something like:

```
$text = "test";

class Task {
    private $title;
    private $description;

    function SetTitle($t) {
        $this->title = $t;
    }

    function GetTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function SetDescription($d) {
        $this->description = $d;
    }

    function GetDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }
}

$t = new Task();
$t->SetTitle($text);

$output = $t->GetTitle();
echo $output;
```

So you will know for sure if the php file hasn't an error.
Same in the html/javascript put a `console.log(inputValue)` to see what are you sending.

If all is working you do the `$t->SetTitle($_POST['title']);`